# Mapping own keyboard input using chrome extension which able directly edit in google docs

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, keyboard, chromium, ime

I trying develop an extension to remapping own keyboard input method for my project. But i realize that my keyboard input method doesn't work inside google docs for chrome/chromium. I want to ask is it anyway to create an chrome IME extension like Google Input Tools which able to directly use chrome extension to type the language input method following the input method we choose in the extension but not in google docs? Like in mac we can use Ukelele(Mac OS X Keyboard Layout Editor) to create and remapping our own style keyboard layout(which can use in ipage too!).
If there is a way is it possible to share out. Thank you!

Comment: To my best knowledge, I don't think it's possible. Even with the extension Google input tool, you can't edit in google docs. People can use docs input tool (keyboard option) or add-on (not pretty sure) do it instead.

Comment: Because my project require to create keyboard mapping for different os, for mac and window finish doing but when come to chrome. I have no idea how to settle it down. Hope someone can give answer. or is it ibus possible?